# Formula using Cells in the spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, formulas

I am looking for a way to set a variable equal to the number of non-empty cells in Column A using Excel VBA.

So pseudo code

```
Dim j As Integer
j = CountA(A:A)
```

This however does not work. Neither does `j = "=CountA(A:A)"`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do the trick.
The VBA functions don't work exactly the same as in the spreadsheets themselves.  You need to first select the range of the active worksheet and then call the counta function.

```
Dim j = Application.WorksheetFunction.counta(activeworksheet.range("A:A"))
```

Comment: There are at least two errors in this line of code (one in compile and one in run-time)

Answer (score 0):

Paste this into a module in Excel VBA.

```
Function CountNonEmptyCells(ColId As Integer) As Integer
Dim r As Range
Dim Count As Integer
Set r = Sheet1.Columns(ColId)
For Each cell In r.Cells
If cell.Value <> "" Then
Count = Count + 1
End If
Next
CountNonEmptyCells = Count
End Function
```

My end result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use *Evaluate Function* like this:

```
Dim j As Long
j = [CountA(A:A)] 'brackets are shortcut for Evaluate
```

or explicitly like this:

```
j = Evaluate("CountA(A:A)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you can either *Evaluate* the formula as it would appear on the worksheet or you can adapt the syntax to use as an adopted VBA command. Here are a couple variations of each. Note that I am explicitly including a reference to the parent worksheet. This is particularly important for the first two *evaluate* methods and desirable for all four variations in order that you are not counting column A from the wrong worksheet.

```
Dim j As Long
j = [COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)]
Debug.Print j
j = Evaluate("COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)")
Debug.Print j
j = Application.CountA(Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1))
Debug.Print j
j = Application.CountA(Range("Sheet1!A:A"))
Debug.Print j
```

The first simply uses **[** and **]** as wrappers around the `COUNTA` formula as it would appear on the worksheet. This forces evaluation of the formula to a result. The second is another evaluation of the formula but using the `.Evaluate` command allows you the option to construct the formula as a string using concatenation, replacement and other text parsing methods. You can include an *equals* sign (e.g. =) as a prefix if that makes more sense to you, (e.g. `j = [=COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)]`) but it is not necessary.

In the last two, VBA adopts the native worksheet `COUNTA` function by prefacing it with either `Application.Worksheetfunction.` or (as above) just `Application.`. The cell range also moves from worksheet cell notation to VBA style cell notation.